# Implementing a directive in Angular 4 to continuously cycle through background colors on host

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, lifecycle-hook

I'm learning angular 4 and would like to implement a directive that causes the host element's background colors to cycle through the 7 listed in an array. Ideally I would want it to be continuous. I don't know which life-cycle hooks I need to hook into.
Here's what I have at the moment. Presently, it's not even *visibly* cycling through the 7 one time, with one-second intervals, as expected through the use of the `SetTimeOut`. I've commented out the `While` block as that just hangs the browser.

```
import {
  Directive,
  OnInit,
  HostBinding,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: '[rainbowize]'
})
export class RainbowizeDirective {
  colors: Array<string>;

 @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') bgColor: string;

  constructor() {
    this.colors = ['violet', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'];
 }

 ngOnInit(){
   let that = this;
   //while (true) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        console.log(that.colors[i]);
        setTimeout(function () {
          that.bgColor = that.colors[i];
        }, 1000)
      }
    //}
  }
}
```

html:

```
<h2 rainbowize >This is a raibowized paragraph</h2>
```

Comment: `//while (true) {` - this will freeze the browser because you're blocking the main thread. does it work if you set it only once?

Comment: It works in the sense of cycling through the colours in the array. I see this when I console.log colors[i]. However, it reaches the last color with apparently no delay. And I only see the eventual red on the element on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let that = this;
    let counter = 0;
    let length = this.colors.length;

    upd();

    function upd() {
        that.bgColor = that.colors[counter % length];
        counter++;

        // some stopping condition here
        if (counter < 20) {
            setTimeout(upd, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

The most important thing here is this line:

```
that.colors[counter % length];
```

I use modulo operator `%`, which returns remainder after the integer division. So it will return:

```
0%7 = 0
1%7 = 1
2%7 = 2
...
6%7 = 6
7%7 = 0  <---- here the sequence starts from the beginning
8%7 = 1
```

This will run until the `counter` variable reaches `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is `9007199254740991`.

Another simpler approach could be to just do the following:

```
    that.bgColor = that.colors[counter % length];
    counter++;

    if (counter === length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
```

Or use a circular linked list.

> But I'm still not clear as to where my error lies? Is it because I
>   have my code in the ngOnInit's main body as opposed to having it a
>   function there?

The problem with your code has nothing to do with Angular. It is that you're adding all callbacks to be executed within a second. And since they are all executed very fast, you only see the latest change to red. You could fix it like this:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    console.log(that.colors[i]);
    setTimeout(function () {
      that.bgColor = that.colors[i];
    }, 1000*i+1)
       ^^^^^^ --------------
  }
```

But the problem now remains that your loop executes only once, so each callback is scheduled only once.

Comment: Thanks for explanation on using modulus for cycling through an array. Nifty! I've since changed to using `Array.shift()` and `.push()`, in fact. 
But I'm still not clear as to where my error lies? Is it because I have my code in the `ngOnInit`'s main body as opposed to having it a function there?
Or am I missing some other logic?

Comment: @PatrickGomes, I've added some clarification, see if it helps

Comment: I think my problem may be my not properly understanding how the callback works here, or how setTimeout does.  Just not sure why  the color, being changed inside the setTimeout function with a delay of 1 second each time it executes does not 'hold' each color on the screen for one second -- or why changing the delay to 1000*i+1 should accomplish the task. I'm missing something but don't know what. Does it have to do with the peculiarity of async calls?

Comment: here `setTimeout(function () {
          that.bgColor = that.colors[i];
        }, 1000)` you're just adding all functions to the queue and they are executed one after another very quickly, put a `console.log` there to see. here `setTimeout(function () {
      that.bgColor = that.colors[i];
    }, 1000*i+1)` I'm adding all functions to be executed with in interval of  1 second, the first will be executed immediately, next in 1 second, next in 2 seconds etc

Comment: I realise I didn't really understand how the async setTimeout() worked. Now I do. Thanks!